# Get the current html content of UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I load a html template from the `NSBundle` using `UIWebView`'s `loadRequest` method. The html template itself have large number of textboxes (say 20). After I fill all the textboxes I want the html with these filled values. I tried,

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]
//even body.outerHTML, documentElement.innerHTML won't work
```

But it is giving me the raw html template before these values filled. How can I do it?
I am thinking this to do this, by reading the content of each textboxes, by javascript,

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('name').value"]
```

and then read and replace the strings of the html.

Is there any other better way to do this? Or is there any javascript methods to read the current content of the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right that `.innerHTML` and `.outerHTML` won't give you the updated state of the DOM.

However, since your are already into querying by Javascript, you can create a JSON string containing a list of all the currently entered values:

```
NSString *jsonString = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function(fields) { var O=[]; for(var i=0; i<fields.length;i++) {O.push(fields[i].value);} return JSON.stringify(O); })(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'))"];
```

You can then parse that in your native code an if it worked it should come out as an `NSArray` of strings.